# Why is .net's StringFormat.SetDigitSubstitution method not working at all?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to replace standard digits with traditional ones:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP");
using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular))
{
    using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat())
    {
        format.SetDigitSubstitution(culture.LCID, StringDigitSubstitute.Traditional);
        g.DrawString("Digits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0", font, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle, format);
    }
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.setdigitsubstitution?view=netframework-4.8), this code should have printed traditional characters insted of western digits, but this is not the case. I also tried using "UD Digi Kyokasho NK-R" (a Japanese font) for the FontFamily argument, but it still draws western digits.

I am trying to achieve this on Windows Forms, and testing on Windows 10, using .net framework 4.7.2.

The issue is present for all languages, as far as I found.

Comment: You probably have in `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NativeDigits` the (so called) Western digits. While, as in the msdn example, Arabic (`ar-EG`, Egypt) and Thai (`th-TH`, Thailand) have a `NativeDigits` definition. `Traditional` is a user localization which may differ from the national/official one (if none is defined, it's the same as in `NativeDigits`). The `CultureInfo` definitions are system-specific. In Windows 10 you may have a different result than in Windows 7, for example. It also depends on the System updates.

Comment: If I remember correctly digit substitution only works in WPF, not WinForms as the former has its own drawing engine, while WinForms just uses Windows standard controls.

Comment: @ckuri It works. You can just try the code the OP provided using one of the cultures I mentioned above. It's a `StringFormat` function and the strings are drawn using `Graphics.DrawString()`. WinForms controls, here, are not even involved.

Comment: @Jimi The issue is present for all languages, as far as I found. This includes the entire MSDN example and I tried a couple of others as well.

Comment: Works in Windows 7 :) (it's a System-specific setting, right?) In Windows 10, the Region/Format settings => `Standard Digits` and `Use native digits` have been removed for a reason. See this: [Digit Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/digit-shapes#digit-substitution) in [National Language Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/national-language-support) and (from Michael Kaplan's blog) [Digits -- there is no substitute](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/01/18/514171.html). Also, see the docs about `Uniscribe`.